# Unable to connect to Dash app running with Docker and hosted on EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, plotly-dash

I know that (many) versions of this question have been asked, but none of them have solved my problem. I have a Dash app that is running with Docker on an AWS EC2 instance. I would like to access it from my browser (Firefox), but I keep getting the `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 17.67.12.567:8085` (I have changed the public IPv4 address, `17.67.12.567` from the actual one I am using, but that shouldn't matter?).

I run the app with `docker run -t -i -p 80:80 app_name`, which outputs:

```
[2021-10-27 08:15:00 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-10-27 08:15:00 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8085 (1)
[2021-10-27 08:15:00 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads
[2021-10-27 08:15:00 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2021-10-27 08:15:00 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2021-10-27 08:15:00 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2021-10-27 08:15:00 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

So, I would expect to be able to access the app at `http:17.67.12.567:8085`, but, when I do this, I get the `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 17.67.12.567:8085` error.

I have read a lot about firewalls and security group settings, and the EC2 instance's security group settings are as open as possible, I think (I know this is a bad idea, but I will narrow them down once I can access the app!); below is a screenshot of the EC2 instance's security group settings.

[image]

That is all the information that I can think to give, thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I figured this out about five minutes after posting, sorry, but hopefully this helps some other poor soul that is working on a project that they do not totally understand!

The problem was the with the port mapping; it needs to match exactly the port shown in `Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8085 (1)`. So, instead of using `docker run -t -i -p 80:80 app_name` I needed to use `docker run -t -i 8085:8085 app_name`.

Once I ran the app with `docker run -t -i 8085:8085 app_name` I was able to access it on `http:17.67.12.567:8085`, as expected.

Thank you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61619707/6909598) for guidance!